# Dynamic search -- Laravel whereRaw not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to search for a record in the Individualprofile model based on a search key. The route below when viewed from the browser throws a `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereRaw()` exception.

Inside the foreach loop I have tried `Individualprofile::whereRaw(..)` but still the same problem.

Below is my full route implementation.

```
Route::get('/get-individualprofiles',function(){
        $text = "Lamin";
        if(trim($text) == ""){
            return Individualprofile::take(10)->get();
        }

        $substr = preg_split("/[\s,.()&;:_-]+/",preg_replace("/(\w+)/","%$1%",trim($text)),-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

        $profiles = Individualprofile::all();
        foreach ($substr as $key) {
            $profiles = $profiles->whereRaw('(name like ? or mobile like ? or address like ? or occupation like ? or mstatus like ?)',[$key,$key,$key,$key,$key]);
        }
        return $profiles->take(100)->get();
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying use a Query Builder method with a Collection instance. Try using this:

```
$profiles = Individualprofile::query();

foreach ($substr as $key) {
    $profiles = $profiles->whereRaw('(name like ? or mobile like ? or address like ? or occupation like ? or mstatus like ?)',[$key,$key,$key,$key,$key]);
}

return $profiles->take(100)->get();
```

`Individualprofile::all()` returns the result of `get()` which means you get a `Collection` not a `Builder` instance which has the `whereRaw` method. The `query()` method will return a `Builder` instance for your model, which you can use to build your query.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. I have to start looking at the API right away.